# error between sum and integral using big oh notation

Tags: number-theory, summation

[image]

i am trying to get error by using big oh notation

i tried using euler’s summation formula but it didn’t work

how can i get O(x^-sigma) from there?

hint will be appreciated

—————my work—————-
[image]

Comment: The first appearance of $O(x^{-\sigma})$ comes from integral comparison.  Just draw out the curce $\frac{1}{u^{\sigma}}$ for $u \in [x,N]$ and compare with the Riemann sum of left rectangles of width 1.  (By the way, it's $\sigma$ and not $s$ because "size" only depends on the real part.)

Comment: @Dzoooks  I did as you mentioned and it worked thank you and also appreciate the reason for why it’s sigma

Comment: Presumably, $\sigma$ is meant to be the real part of the complex variable $s$. Anyway, if you now understand, let me encourage you to write it up and post it as an answer.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson well..I think I can’t call it as an answer but anyway i tried